# Asyncio imap fetch mails python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, imap, python-asyncio

I'm testing with the asyncio module, however I need a hint / suggesstion how to fetch large emails in an async way.

I have a list with usernames and passwords for the mail accounts.

```
data = [
    {'usern': 'foo@bar.de', 'passw': 'x'},
    {'usern': 'foo2@bar.de', 'passw': 'y'},
    {'usern': 'foo3@bar.de', 'passw': 'z'} (...)
]
```

I thought about:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait([get_attachment(d) for d in data]))
loop.close()
```

However, the long part is to download the email attachments.

Email:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def get_attachment(d):
    username = d['usern']
    password = d['passw']

    connection = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.bar.de')
    connection.login(username, password)
    connection.select()

    # list all available mails
    typ, data = connection.search(None, 'ALL')

    for num in data[0].split():
        # fetching each mail
        typ, data = connection.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
        raw_string = data[0][1].decode('utf-8')
        msg = email.message_from_string(raw_string)
        for part in msg.walk():
            if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
                continue

            if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
                continue

            if part.get_filename():
                body = part.get_payload(decode=True)
                # do something with the body, async?

    connection.close()
    connection.logout()
```

How could I process all (downloading attachments) mails in an async way?

Comment: Imaplib is a synchronous library, you can fake it with threads and the like, but it will never be truly asynchronous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't have an asynchronous I/O-based imap library, you can just use a `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` to do the I/O in threads. Python will release the GIL during the I/O, so you'll get true concurrency:

```
def init_connection(d):    
    username = d['usern']
    password = d['passw']

    connection = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.bar.de')
    connection.login(username, password)
    connection.select()
    return connection

local = threading.local() # We use this to get a different connection per thread
def do_fetch(num, d, rfc):
    try:
        connection = local.connection
    except AttributeError:
        connnection = local.connection = init_connection(d)
    return connnection.fetch(num, rfc)

@asyncio.coroutine
def get_attachment(d, pool):
    connection = init_connection(d)    
    # list all available mails
    typ, data = connection.search(None, 'ALL')

    # Kick off asynchronous tasks for all the fetches
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    futs = [asyncio.create_task(loop.run_in_executor(pool, do_fetch, num, d, '(RFC822)'))
                for num in data[0].split()]

    # Process each fetch as it completes
    for fut in asyncio.as_completed(futs):
        typ, data = yield from fut
        raw_string = data[0][1].decode('utf-8')
        msg = email.message_from_string(raw_string)
        for part in msg.walk():
            if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
                continue

            if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
                continue

            if part.get_filename():
                body = part.get_payload(decode=True)
                # do something with the body, async?

    connection.close()
    connection.logout()    


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)  # You can probably increase max_workers, because the threads are almost exclusively doing I/O.
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait([get_attachment(d, pool) for d in data]))
loop.close()
```

This isn't quite as nice as a truly asynchronous I/O-based solution, because you've still got the overhead of creating the threads, which limits scalability and adds extra memory overhead. You also do get *some* GIL slowdown because of all the code wrapping the actual I/O calls. Still, if you're dealing with less than thousands of mails, it should still perform ok.

We use [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.run_in_executor) to use the `ThreadPoolExecutor` as part of the asyncio event loop, [`asyncio.async`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.async) to wrap the coroutine object returned in a `asyncio.Future`, and [`as_completed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.as_completed) to iterate through the futures in the order they complete.

**Edit**:

It seems `imaplib` is not thread-safe. I've edited my answer to use thread-local storage via [`threading.local`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/threading.html#thread-local-data), which allows us to create one connection object per-thread, which can be re-used for the entire life of the thread (meaning you create `num_workers` connection objects only, rather than a new connection for every `fetch`).

Comment: Thanks, this approach is what I was looking for. However receive some errors while running workers > 1. See here: https://gist.github.com/wiesson/5d611016ec223993e25d

Why you are calling the asyncio.get_event_loop in the get_attachment loop?

Comment: @wiesson There's actually no need to call get_event_loop, since you can use the global one. Re: the errors you're seeing, my guess is that `imaplib` isn't thread safe, and would therefore require a connection object per-thread. You can use `threading.local()` to help with that. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: asyncio.async SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @tnusraddinov Since I've posted this answer `asyncio.async` has been deprecated and removed. `asyncio.create_task` should be used instead. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same needs : fetching emails with python 3 fully async. If others here are interested I pushed an asyncio IMAP lib here : https://github.com/bamthomas/aioimaplib

You can use it like this :

```
import asyncio
from aioimaplib import aioimaplib

@asyncio.coroutine
def wait_for_new_message(host, user, password):
    imap_client = aioimaplib.IMAP4(host=host)
    yield from imap_client.wait_hello_from_server()

    yield from imap_client.login(user, password)
    yield from imap_client.select()

    asyncio.async(imap_client.idle())
    id = 0
    while True:
        msg = yield from imap_client.wait_server_push()
        print('--> received from server: %s' % msg)
        if 'EXISTS' in msg:
            id = msg.split()[0]
            imap_client.idle_done()
            break

    result, data = yield from imap_client.fetch(id, '(RFC822)')
    email_message = email.message_from_bytes(data[0])

    attachments = []
    body = ''
    for part in email_message.walk():
        if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
            continue
        if part.get_content_maintype() == 'text' and 'attachment' not in part.get('Content-Disposition', ''):
            body = part.get_payload(decode=True).decode(part.get_param('charset', 'ascii')).strip()
        else:
            attachments.append(
                {'type': part.get_content_type(), 'filename': part.get_filename(), 'size': len(part.as_bytes())})

    print('attachments : %s' % attachments)
    print('body : %s' % body)
    yield from imap_client.logout()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(wait_for_new_message('my.imap.server', 'user', 'pass'))
```

Large emails with attachments are also downloaded with asyncio.

Comment: As a warning: there exist servers that will send `* n EXISTS` (n unchanged) as a keepalive during IDLE.  On these servers you will fetch the same message repeatedly here.

Comment: There's an `'email' is not defined` error on running the code. I think the line `import email` should be included.

Comment: There's also an error `Module asyncio has no async member`